# Objective-C Generated Interface Header Cannot Find Pod Header

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I am having a problem with a Pod in Xcode. It has both Objective-C and Swift, and I just added some more Swift classes to it. However, now when building, the Objective-C Generated Interface Header file (Test_Pod-Swift.h) cannot find the Test_Pod.h file, so it isn't building.
The pod is called Test_Pod, and the Interface Header file says "'Test_Pod/Test_Pod.h' file not found".
It seems to only happen after making the classes public, which is needed for access outside of the pod, but I dont understand how that is breaking the build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be the same issue as in this thread: [Building a Cocoapod with both Swift and Objective-C: How to Deal with Umbrella Header Issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38192343/building-a-cocoapod-with-both-swift-and-objective-c-how-to-deal-with-umbrella-h?rq=1)

Adding the header to the top level of pod classes and naming it "Test_Pod.h" with just:

```
#import "Test_Pod-umbrella.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `Test_Pod` from your project and reinstalling it

```
pod deintegrate
pod install
```